# Как определить куда девается дисковое пространство

Tags: xcode, macos, mac

Пользуюсь программой `LevelHelper` и `Xcode`, с неделю назад было свободно 90Гб, и постепенно это место съедается во время работы этих программ (больше склоняюсь что это из-за `LevelHelper`), сейчас у меня 3Гб не могу понять куда это место девается.
Думал что Кеши остаются и накапливаются, но в папках с кешами пусто.

Может кто подсказать как найти куда делось это место, и как вычислить папку с таким большим объемом хлама?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать [командой du](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/du.1.html)

Comment: @avp я так понимаю последняя строчка команды показывает общий объем.. там пишет "37G", при этом в разделе Хранилище пишет что у меня чисто Системой занято 147 Гб.

Comment: Ну, я же не вижу где и из под кого вы du запускаете... Посмотрите (df) какие у вас вообще файловые системы подмонтированы и сколько там занято и свободно. Потом (лучше от рута) запускаете du и исследуете ее вывод. Вообще-то все должно сходиться.